# R data.table fread suppress messages

Tags: r, data.table

When I use fread to read large data files (lets say 250MB) using the following statement

`myFile<-fread(rawFile,skip=1,sep=",",header=FALSE)`

It always gives read status of the file like

`Read 2859078 rows and 6 (of 6) columns from 0.272 GB file in 00:00:05`

I tried methods like `suppressMessages` to suppress this. But it doesn't work.

Is there any `data.table` specific command to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `fread(file,..., showProgress = FALSE)`

Comment: is there any way to suppress messages like `trying URL 'http://...'` when freading from csv over the web?